# Change default shell on nitrous.io box?

Tags: nitrousio

On a nitrous.io drogo box, how do I change the default shell to zsh when I ssh in? I do not have write access to /etc/passwd, and I cannot sudo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use zsh in the main console, but you could with tmux (which is already installed). You will just need to add this line into ~/.tmux.conf :

```
set-option -g default-shell /bin/zsh
```